# How to add TextBox in MessageBox in WindowsPhone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, messagebox

Here i need to add textbox to messagebox.but the message box dose not adding the textbox,how can i add it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless Phone is different, message boxes don't normally support custom controls - they have fixed controls. You probably need to create your own little form instead. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/07/creating-a-global-progressindicator-experience-using-the-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-beta-2/). 

They have the control **Input Prompt** which shows a message box with text-box.

Answer (score 1):

If all you require is a simple InputBox like in Visual Basic, you can use the [Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975190%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) method from [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) to show a TextBox requesting user input.

Use it like so:

```
Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput(PlayerIndex.One, "caption", "text", "defaultText", ar =>
{
    text = Guide.EndShowKeyboardInput(ar);

    //Do something with the text here!
}, null);
```

If you are using MVVM architecture in your application, you can also use InputBoxService on the [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](https://github.com/PedroLamas/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit) for a cleaner approach!